# Paul Irish's log.history

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how to use log.history in Paul Irish's [lightweight wrapper for console.log](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog).

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the JS in your page. Something like this:

#### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- snip -->
        <script src="path/to/console/wrapper.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><!-- snip --></body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript

```
// drop this in the file referenced above
window.log=function(){log.history=log.history||[];log.history.push(arguments);if(this.console){console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))}};
```

This gives you a reverse-chronological history of everything that's been logged, stored in `log.history`. Want to see the first thing logged?

```
> log.history[0]
```

Want to the the last thing logged?

```
> log.history.slice(-1)
```

Comment: Wouldn't I see the first and last thing logged in the console log?  I'm not trying to be funny or cute.  I really don't understand the point of log.history.

Comment: I agree, it's not _insanely_ useful. One use I could see is for retrieving old `console.log()`s after you (say, accidentally) cleared the console. Uses that Paul Irish notes: Prevent errors if a console isn't around (i.e. IE); Maintain a history of logs, so you can look in the past if your console is added afterwards (e.g. firebug lite); Normalize the browser differences in console integration (e.g. when passing multiple arguments into `console.log()`); For something you type regularly, make it quicker to type for the lazy among us.

Comment: The use case is that.. YOu lazyload in firebug lite in IE and you want the history of what was logged before that console was available. There is a bookmarklet on the page that loads in firebug lite and spits the history into it.

Comment: There you have it, straight from the horse's mouth. Thanks @Paul